Getting the CELL ADDRESS of XLOOKUP result produces "ARGUMENT MUST BE A RANGE" error
The function works perfectly when xlookup is constrained to a single row to search...but when I search multiple rows for my match, suddenly I get an error saying the argument must be a range.
I tried
=cell("address",xlookup($C$4,July!$A$2:$N$2,July!$B4:$O4,"ERROR",0,1))
and it works perfectly. The date for C4 on my current sheet are to be found in July's A2,C2,E2,G2,I2,K2, or M2 and the results I want will be in July's B4,D4,F4,H4,J4,L4, or N4
once I introduced multiple rows to search (aka different weeks on a calendar layout), then I get an error.
=cell("address",xlookup($C$4,{July!$A$2:$N$2,July!$A$11:$N$11,July!$A$20:$N$20,July!$A$29:$N$29,July!$A$38:$N$38,July!$A$47:$N$47},{July!$B4:$O4,July!$B13:$O13,July!$B22:$O22,July!$B31:$O31,July!$B40:$O40,July!$B49:$O49},"ERROR",0,1))
I assume this is because I introduced arrays. My result is still only a single cell. What's the work around? How can I get the address of my result.
Thank you so much!!

Please post your data using Markdown language (https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#google_vignette).

I'm not sure about the final goal, but you could try this (Excel 365):

Get the addresses for the range
Use CHOOSEROWS to select non-adjacent rows (ranges start with the first row, $A$1 and $B$1, to use row numbers)
Convert both to columns to use with XLOOKUP

=LET(
    a_rows, CHOOSEROWS(
        July!$A1:$N47,
        2,
        11,
        20,
        29,
        38,
        47
    ),
    b_range, $B$1:$O$49,
    b_addr, CHOOSEROWS(
        ADDRESS(ROW(b_range), COLUMN(b_range)),
        4,
        13,
        22,
        31,
        40,
        49
    ),
    XLOOKUP($C$4, TOCOL(a_rows), TOCOL(b_addr), "ERROR")
)


Thanks for the suggestion, this is smart! but if I use this I get a circular dependency error.

is there anyway to convert an array to a non-array?

also, I'm not sure, but I think that even if it didn't give a circular reference error, I think it would give an error that xlookup requires a single row or column (even though  it can function with arrays)

Please make sure enter this in a cell outside ranges used in the formula (outside A1:O49). Then you shouldn't get the circular ref error. I usually try to use INDEX to avoid array results. I'd look into this more if you could provide more details about your end goal.

Ultimately, I misunderstood the issue, but this is the work-around I eventually settled on:
=iferror(cell("ADDRESS",xlookup($C$4,January!$A$2:$N$2,January!$B4:$O4,100/0,0,1)),
iferror(cell("ADDRESS",xlookup($C$4,January!$A$11:$N$11,January!$B13:$O13,100/0,0,1)),
iferror(cell("ADDRESS",xlookup($C$4,January!$A$20:$N$20,January!$B22:$O22,100/0,0,1)),
iferror(cell("ADDRESS",xlookup($C$4,January!$A$29:$N$29,January!$B31:$O31,100/0,0,1)),
iferror(cell("ADDRESS",xlookup($C$4,January!$A$38:$N$38,January!$B40:$O40,100/0,0,1)),
iferror( cell("ADDRESS",xlookup($C$4,January!$A$47:$N$47,January!$B49:$O49,"DATE NOT FOUND",0,1))))))))

